# django-tinymce fails to display the widget properly

Tags: python, django, django-admin, tinymce, django-tinymce

I'm trying to use to django-tinymce (http://http://django-tinymce.googlecode.com/ ) app to display a WYSIWYG editor in the django admin.

I downloaded and installed it, downloaded the tinymce itself and put it into /js/tiny_mce, did not change anything in the settings.py and added an HTMLField to my model like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  text  = tinymce.models.HTMLField()
  ...
```

When I add a new entry through the django-admin, the tinyMCE is there, but it's all butchered up - no toolbar, no statusbar, just a plain white space where I can type. Bold/italic hotkeys work.

I use lighttpd to serve tinymce's javascripts and django's builtin server for the rest.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:
Ok, I'm not sure why exactly, but the cause of this was that lighttpd was sending improper content-types for .js'es and .css'es in response headers. Fixed by modifying lighttpd config.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it :-)

Comment: Yea,I tried that and was told that I could accept my own answer only in two days :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cause of this was that lighttpd was sending improper content-types for .js'es and .css'es in response headers. Fixed by modifying lighttpd config.